# Using Loc and Replace causes value to replace with None

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I want to replace an object that says "2023-09-01" to "2023-09-30" for a specific loc function that calls in a name.

When I run my code, the "2023-09-01" object is changed to "None" instead of "2023-09-30". It does find the instance though and only replaces that row, but with the wrong information.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
df1['date'].loc[df1['client_name'] == 'sample'] = df1['date'].loc[(df1['client_name'] == 'sample')].replace('2023-09-01', '2023-09-30', inplace=True)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Either use an assignment or `inplace=True`, not both. When you use `inplace=True` it returns `None` instead of the replacement result, and that's what you're assigning.

Comment: Are you sure you need to use `.loc()`?

Answer (score 1):

I see what's going on. The culprit is the inplace=True argument you've used inside the replace function. When you use inplace=True, the function modifies the dataframe directly and returns None. That's why you're seeing the "2023-09-01" value being replaced with None.
Try:

```
df1.loc[df1['client_name'] == 'sample', 'date'] = df1['date'].loc[df1['client_name'] == 'sample'].replace('2023-09-01', '2023-09-30')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df1['date'].loc[df1['client_name'] == 'sample'] = df1['date'].loc[(df1['client_name'] == 'sample')].replace('2023-09-01', '2023-09-30', inplace=True)
```

Any pandas call with inplace set to True will perform the action 'in place' meaning it acts on the existing DataFrame and returns None.

So either you assign the result to a new variable without "inplace=True" or you make the call without a variable assignment. The other thing to note is that you needn't specify the index along with replace.

Another quick note is that you may want to use .loc["row_indexer","column_indexer"] rather than df["column_indexer].loc["row_indexer"]

I've printed just the head and tail of the df examples to remain concise.
All cleaned up your options are:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
#generating dates
today = datetime.datetime(2023,9,30)
dates = [datetime.datetime.strftime(today - datetime.timedelta(i),"%Y-%m-%d") for i in range(30)]

#generating client names
client_names = ['sample_' + str(val+1) for val in range(len(dates))]
index = [i for i in range(len(dates))]
#df creation
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'client_name':client_names,'date':dates}, index=index)

#replacing specified date value
df1["date"] = df1["date"].replace('2023-09-01','2023-09-30',inplace=False)

#date replacement ONLY FOR specific client name
df1.loc[df1["client_name"]=="sample_1","date"] = '2023-09-01'

   
 before adjustments

   client_name        date
0    sample_1  2023-09-30
1    sample_2  2023-09-29
2    sample_3  2023-09-28
3    sample_4  2023-09-27
4    sample_5  2023-09-26
    client_name        date
25   sample_26  2023-09-05
26   sample_27  2023-09-04
27   sample_28  2023-09-03
28   sample_29  2023-09-02
29   sample_30  2023-09-01

 after specific client adjustment, note two instances of 2023-09-01 since "sample_1" was selected

   client_name        date
0    sample_1  2023-09-01
1    sample_2  2023-09-29
2    sample_3  2023-09-28
3    sample_4  2023-09-27
4    sample_5  2023-09-26
    client_name        date
25   sample_26  2023-09-05
26   sample_27  2023-09-04
27   sample_28  2023-09-03
28   sample_29  2023-09-02
29   sample_30  2023-09-01

after date adjustment, note two instances of 2023-09-30 because we specified replacements of any instance of 2023-09-01 (there were two of them)

   client_name        date
0    sample_1  2023-09-30
1    sample_2  2023-09-29
2    sample_3  2023-09-28
3    sample_4  2023-09-27
4    sample_5  2023-09-26
    client_name        date
25   sample_26  2023-09-05
26   sample_27  2023-09-04
27   sample_28  2023-09-03
28   sample_29  2023-09-02
29   sample_30  2023-09-30
```